# How to create new array of dates from existing arrays of dates in PHP?

Tags: php

I have 2 arrays of dates. I need the most efficient way to build a third array of dates that consists of only the dates that are the same from the 2 arrays of dates.

**For example:**

```
List of Dates #1:
2017-01-01
2017-01-02
2017-01-03
2017-02-01
2017-02-02
2017-09-09

List of Dates #2:
2017-01-01
2017-02-01
2017-03-01
2017-04-01

So array 3 should be:
2017-01-01
2017-02-01
```

Comment: May help: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_uintersect.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [array_intersect](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi4nM_frabWAhUHr48KHR3PDaQQFggqMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fen%2Ffunction.array-intersect.php&usg=AFQjCNFzzMy7WWYPPBJ3jo5skgOpmVyRaw):

**Working Demo**: https://eval.in/862254

```
$array1 = array("2017-01-01", "2017-01-01" ,"2017-01-02","2017-01-03","2017-02-01", "2017-02-02","2017-09-09");

$array2 = array("2017-01-01","2017-02-01","2017-03-01","2017-04-01");
$result = array_intersect(array_unique($array1), $array2);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2017-01-01
    [3] => 2017-02-01
)
```

**Note**

> `array_intersect` Returns an array containing all of the values in
>   `$array1` whose values exist in all of the parameters. So if your
>   `$array1`  is having duplicate data then resultant array also have
>   duplicate values.

I have added [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to overcome that situation.

Comment: any way to prevent duplicate entries? that's the kicker for me when I tried this. The output must not contain duplicate entries even if there are multiple overlapping dates.

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: Do you also know how I can make reference to the first, second, etc values in this array if they are labelled like your output where they may not be [0], [1], [2], etc?

Comment: for example a for loop would not be able to cycle through the records using an increment like $i... for ($i = 0; $i <= count($array) - 1; $i++) {... because the out has varying labelling numbers, in the case of your output 0 then 3

Answer (score 0):

Maybe **array_intersect()** ?

```
$array1 = array ("a" => "green", "red", "blue");
$array2 = array ("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_intersect ($array1, $array2);
```

result

```
Array
(
    [a] => green
    [0] => red
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function myfunction($a,$b)
{
if ($a===$b)
  {
  return 0;
  }
  return ($a>$b)?1:-1;
}

$a1=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","yellow");
$a2=array("A"=>"red","b"=>"GREEN","yellow","black");
$a3=array("a"=>"green","b"=>"red","yellow","black");

$result=array_uintersect($a1,$a2,$a3,"myfunction");
print_r($result);
```

Result:

```
Array ( [a] => red [0] => yellow )
```